# Display month along with its year

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I have an array like so:

```
1 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#714 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#723 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "November"
]
2 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#721 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#717 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "December"
]
3 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#729 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#730 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "January"
]
4 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#732 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#733 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "February"
]
```

Now what I want is to append a year to the `monthName` key after adding the months from `subscription_start_month` key.

Example of what I want:

```
2 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#721 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#717 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "December, 2016" // <-- The current year
]
3 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => "4"
  "order_code" => "BS-ORD-000000004"
  "order_type" => "Mixed - Subscription"
  "subscription_months" => "4"
  "subscription_start_month" => Carbon {#729 ▼
    +"date": "2016-11-05 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "subscription_end_month" => Carbon {#730 ▼
    +"date": "2017-03-04 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "monthName" => "January, 2017" // <-- The next year
]
```

I have the tried the following code, but it does not work as expected.

```
$startMonthForMixed = $invoice->subscription_start_date->month;

for($i = 0; $i < $invoice->subscription_months; $i++) {
    $convertedInvoices[] = [
        'id' => $invoice->id,
        'order_code'               => $invoice->order_code,
        'order_type'               => 'Mixed - Subscription',
        'subscription_months'      => $invoice->subscription_months,
        'subscription_start_month' => $invoice->subscription_start_date,
        'subscription_end_month'   => $invoice->subscription_end_date,
        'monthName'                => date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $startMonthForMixed, 01)) . ", " . Carbon::now()->addYear()
     ];
     $startMonthForMixed++;
 }
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Scenario: A user makes a subscription on October 2016 for 6 months.. So, the array will look something like this:

```
[
    "subscription_months" => 6
    "subscription_start_month => "01-10-2016" // <-- will be carbon instance
    "subscription_end_month => "31-03-2017" // <-- will be carbon instance
    "monthName" => "October"
]
```

The above array I am showing is only 1 month.. There will be 5 more elements in the array..

What I want is, I want to append the `Year` after `monthName`..

So the array should look like this:

```
[
    [
        "monthName" => "October, 2016" // <-- for 1st month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "November, 2016" // <-- for 2nd month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "December, 2016" // <-- for 3rd month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "January, 2017" // <-- for 4th month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "February, 2017" // <-- for 5th month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "March, 2017" // <-- for 6th month
    ]
]
```

How can I achieve that ? Kindly help me out..

Comment: Not sure to understand which year you want to add. Year from start date or year from end date?

Comment: @MassimilianoArione It depends, based on the year, after adding the `subscription_months` to `subscription_end_month`..

Comment: @MassimilianoArione I have added the **UPDATE 1** part, kindly have a look at it..

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have Carbon objects in there, you could use the [`year`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) property:

```
foreach($data as $i => $row) {
    $data[$i]["monthName"] .= ", " . $row["subscription_start_month"]->year;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just format the date from scratch, with Carbon's [`format`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting):

```
foreach($data as $i => $row) {
    $data[$i]["monthName"] = $row["subscription_start_month"]->format('F, Y');
}
```

Comment: I will get only the `subscription_start_month`'s year.. What I need is slightly different from what you have provided me as the solution.. I have added **UPDATE 1**, have a look at it.. You will get the idea of what I am looking for..

Comment: That is an essential change in your question. Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: Checkout the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169733/displaying-of-month-and-its-year-based-on-condition I have asked the question as you suggested.. Kindly help me out.

Comment: I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38169960/5459839) to your other question. Maybe you could remove that follow-up question from this question? And could you let me know if the answer here answered to the original question? ;-)