# Displaying of month and it's year based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, date, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

In my Laravel 5.1 application, I have a feature of Subscription. It is working to a certain extent, but not what I am looking for..

**Scenario**: A user makes a subscription on October 2016 for 6 months.. So, the array will look something like this:

```
[
    "subscription_months" => 6
    "subscription_start_month" => "01-10-2016" // <-- will be carbon instance
    "subscription_end_month => "31-03-2017" // <-- will be carbon instance
    "monthName" => "October"
]
```

The above array I am showing is only 1 month.. There will be 5 more elements in the array..

What I want is, I want to append the `Year` after `monthName`

So, it would look something like this.

```
[
    [
        "monthName" => "October, 2016" // <-- for 1st month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "November, 2016" // <-- for 2nd month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "December, 2016" // <-- for 3rd month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "January, 2017" // <-- for 4th month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "February, 2017" // <-- for 5th month
    ]

    [
        "monthName" => "March, 2017" // <-- for 6th month
    ]
]
```

The code that I have tried so far is:

```
$startMonthForMixed = $invoice->subscription_start_date->month;

for($i = 0; $i < $invoice->subscription_months; $i++) {
    $convertedInvoices[] = [
        'id' => $invoice->id,
        'order_code'               => $invoice->order_code,
        'order_type'               => 'Mixed - Subscription',
        'subscription_months'      => $invoice->subscription_months,
        'subscription_start_month' => $invoice->subscription_start_date,
        'subscription_end_month'   => $invoice->subscription_end_date,
        'monthName'                => date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $startMonthForMixed, 01)) . ", " . Carbon::now()->addYear()
     ];
     $startMonthForMixed++;
 }
```

Can anybody help out with this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the monthName property together with all other properties? or as a sub-array with just monthNames, which resides inside the record that has the other properties?

Comment: @trincot I need monthName property together with all other properties.. But you know what, either of them would work for me..

Comment: @splash58 don't you think `date("F, Y");` would return the currentt timestamp's year and month ??

Comment: @SaiyanPrince Why not? - https://eval.in/599829 I seems don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

The code you have tried with will always use the current year, so it would not work if the subscription period is in another year.

You could use this variation on your code, which makes use of some Carbon and DateTime methods:

```
// take copy of start date
$subscription_month = $invoice->subscription_start_date->copy();

for($i = 0; $i < $invoice->subscription_months; $i++) {
    $convertedInvoices[] = [
        'id' => $invoice->id,
        'order_code'               => $invoice->order_code,
        'order_type'               => 'Mixed - Subscription',
        'subscription_months'      => $invoice->subscription_months,
        'subscription_start_month' => $invoice->subscription_start_date,
        'subscription_end_month'   => $invoice->subscription_end_date,
        'monthName'                => $subscription_month->format("F, Y")
    ];
    // move to first date of following month
    $subscription_month->modify('first day of next month');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cycle for the number of months, using the `add` method of Carbon object to add 1 month. Then, formatting is just a matter of calling `format` method, as trincot already suggested